# How to bindParam with two values in foreach?

Tags: php

I apologise in advance if this question has already been asked. However, I'm not sure what I should have searched in order to find the answer to my question hence asking.

I am trying to use a $_POST[''] variable in a foreach loop to INSERT a different value for every time the query runs. If I am not explaining that correctly, please view my code below.

```
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"])) {
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm) {
        $stmtoD->bindParam(':OrderID', $_SESSION['newOrderID']);
        $stmtoD->bindParam(':ProductCode', $cart_itm["ProductCode"]);
        $stmtoD->bindParam(':Variation', $_POST['product_variation']);
        $stmtoD->bindParam(':ProductName', $cart_itm["ProductName"]);
        $stmtoD->bindParam(':Quantity', $cart_itm["product_qty"]);
        $stmtoD->bindParam(':Cost', $cart_itm["Price"]);
        $stmtoD->execute();
    }
}
```

The problem is the `bindParam :Variation`. I am sending `$_POST['product_variation']` from my Shopping Cart page which obviously shows the products you have in your basket. If you have two products with variations it will only INSERT the variation of the last product added rather than the individual value for each product?

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple, don't take post_variation from `$_POST`, take it from your `$cart_item`

```
$cart_item['product_variation']
```

Comment: I knew I would have to base it around the $cart_item... I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: I managed to get it working using this method. However, I had to make a change I didn't really want to make but it isn't a massive issue. Thank you for helping. I'm new to PHP so I am still missing the obvious errors.